# Python: parse links from Google with search

Tags: python, python-requests, google-search

I need to parse links with results after search in Google.
When I try to see code of page and `Ctrl + U` I can't find element with links, what I want.
But When I see code of elements with 
`Ctrl + Shift + I` I can see what elem should I parse to get links.
I use code

```
url = 'https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=' + str(query)
html = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
links = soup.findAll('cite')
```

But it returns empty list, becauses there are not this elements.
I think that `html-code`, that returns `requests.get(url).content` isn't full, so I can't get this elements.
I tried to use `google.search` but it returned error that `it isn't used now.`
Is any way to get links with search in google?

Comment: Try `html = requests.get(url).text`

Comment: @MithileshKumar it doesn't help

Comment: can you print and show `requests.get(url).text`

Comment: @MithileshKumar  it starts with `<!DOCTYPE doctype html>
<html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="ru"><head><meta content="Поиск информации в интернете: веб страницы, картинки, видео и многое другое." name="description"><meta content="noodp" name="robots"><meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"><meta content="/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png" itemprop="image"><title>Google</title><script>(function(){window.google=
`

Comment: what is 'cite' above?

Comment: @MithileshKumar it's links after search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
url = 'https://www.google.ru/search?q=' + str(query)
html = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')
links = soup.findAll('cite')
print([link.text for link in links])
```

For installing `lxml`, please see http://lxml.de/installation.html

*note: The reason I choose `lxml` instead `html.parser` is that sometimes I got incomplete result with html.parser and I don't know why

Answer (score 1):

USe:

```
url = 'https://www.google.ru/search?q=name&rct=' + str(query)
html = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
links = soup.findAll('cite')
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the actual response that you see in the browser, you need to send additional [headers](https://dev.to/dimitryzub/how-to-reduce-chance-being-blocked-while-web-scraping-search-engines-1o46), more specifically `user-agent` (aside from sending [additional query parameters](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls)) which is needed to act as a "real" user visit when the bot or browser sends a fake `user-agent` string to announce themselves as a different client.

That's why you were getting an empty output because you received a different HTML with different elements (`CSS` selectors, `ID`'s, and so on).

You can read more about it in the blog post I wrote about [how to reduce the chance of being blocked while web scraping](https://dev.to/dimitryzub/how-to-reduce-chance-being-blocked-while-web-scraping-search-engines-1o46).

Pass `user-agent`:

```py
headers = {
    'User-agent':
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582'
}

requests.get('URL', headers=headers)
```

---

Code and example in the [online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Scrape-Title-Description-Linkpythonbs4#bs4_results.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582'
}

params = {
  'q': 'minecraft', # query
  'gl': 'us',       # country to search from
  'hl': 'en',       # language
}

html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

for result in soup.select('.tF2Cxc'):
  link = result.select_one('.yuRUbf a')['href']
  print(link, sep='\n')

---------
'''
https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/
https://classic.minecraft.net/
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mojang.minecraftpe&hl=en_US&gl=US
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minecraft
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using [Google Organic API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference is that you don't have to create it from scratch and maintain it over time if something crashes.

Code to integrate:

```py
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "minecraft",
  "hl": "en",
  "gl": "us",
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for result in results["organic_results"]:
  print(result['link'])

-------
'''
https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/
https://classic.minecraft.net/
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mojang.minecraftpe&hl=en_US&gl=US
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minecraft
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.